# Why can you override the initial value of a property defined in a trait that is used in a parent class?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, traits

The PHP docs says the following about overriding trait properties:

> If a trait defines a property then a class can not define a property
>   with the same name unless it is compatible (same visibility and
>   initial value), otherwise a fatal error is issued.

However, when you use a trait in an abstract class, then you can override the properties defined in the trait in a class extending that abstract class:

```php
<?php

trait PropertyTrait
{
    public $prop = 'default';   
}

abstract class A
{
    use PropertyTrait;
}

class B extends A
{
    public $prop = 'overridden';

    public function write()
    {
        echo $this->prop;       
    }
}

$b = new B();

$b->write(); // outputs "overridden"
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/Z1USf)

The code above works, but I can't find any reference about it in the documentation. Is this an intended feature?

Comment: I have some doubts @yivi https://3v4l.org/FPrBP
Without any abstract class I used the trait in B and without any redeclaration, it worked.

Comment: @Sooraj In this last example **you are not overriding the initial value of the property**. The _initial_ (pre-instantiation) value is the same. You are simply assigning a new one on instantiation, when `__construct()` runs. No matter how you define it, a property is a variable. You can assign new values to it after the class is instantiated. Again, that an abstract class is involved is not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because for all intents and purposes `B` is not using `PropertyTrait`. That's used by `A` to compose the abstract class.

`B` has no visibility of what traits `A` is using. If you were to execute `class_uses` on `B`, you'd get an empty array. [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-uses.php), and [example](https://3v4l.org/9pAec).

Since `B` is not using any traits, the class is free to override any inherited properties.

The fact that `A` is an abstract class has no bearing on this. The same behaviour would happen with any class that extended a class that was composed using traits.